Vite React with routing app displaying blank page on github pages
I've been trying to deploy a react app on github pages but it keeps rendering a blank page.
Github repo : https://github.com/GilbertKrantz/UniPal
Deployed link : https://gilbertkrantz.github.io/UniPal/
I've tried a few different things (changing https to http, starting a new repo) each time I've made a git push and waited a while for github to build it but even after hours there is no change.

Where is the deployed page link? I think the problem might be with incorrect sources in the  and  tags.

https://gilbertkrantz.github.io/UniPal/ to be honest i am very confused some time it was about Api key some times 404 error



As I guess, the problem is with the paths after the build. Change the paths in index.html. It should fix the problem; if not, I'll take another look.

It worked, I added "." on all path, but now the firebase apikey is not found, even when I have already added it in the secret environment and on the github action

@WILbertChandra I have never deployed anything with a secret key on GitHub Pages, so I'm not sure how it should work. However, if you don't find a solution in a few days, I can look into how it works.

to be honest, i am really confused, it worked yesteray, like everythin worked flawlessly, but when i redeploy it. it stops working again

@WIlbertChandra As I have observed, the request to https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/log is currently being successfully completed with the API key.

It has worked now
